# uib-datepicker-popup not showing the calendar

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am using Express and AngularJS. I tried to add a date picker with ui-bootstrap module. When I add uib-datepicker, it works fine. But when I tried to add a uib-datepicker-popup the result was like that

[uib-datepicker-popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWRZc.png)

When I click the calendar button, it shows a pop-up but there are only today, clear and close buttons. It do not show the calendar.

Here is my html

```
<div ng-controller="DatepickerPopupDemoCtrl">
<pre>Selected date is: <em>{{dt | date:'fullDate' }}</em></pre>


  <div class="col-md-6">
    <p class="input-group">
      <input type="text" uib-datepicker-popup class="form-control" ng-model="dt" is-open="popup2.opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open2()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
      </span>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the controller

```
app.controller('DatepickerPopupDemoCtrl', function ($scope) {


$scope.today = function() {
    $scope.dt = new Date();
  };
  $scope.today();

  $scope.clear = function() {
    $scope.dt = null;
  };

    $scope.toggleMin = function() {
    $scope.inlineOptions.minDate = $scope.inlineOptions.minDate ? null : new Date();
    $scope.dateOptions.minDate = $scope.inlineOptions.minDate;
  };


  $scope.inlineOptions = {
    customClass: getDayClass,
    minDate: new Date(),
    showWeeks: true
  };

  $scope.dateOptions = {
    dateDisabled: disabled,
    formatYear: 'yy',
    maxDate: new Date(2020, 5, 22),
    minDate: new Date(),
    startingDay: 1
  };

  // Disable weekend selection
  function disabled(data) {
    var date = data.date,
      mode = data.mode;
    return mode === 'day' && (date.getDay() === 0 || date.getDay() === 6);
  }

  $scope.toggleMin();

  $scope.open2 = function() {
    $scope.popup2.opened = !$scope.popup2.opened;
  };

  $scope.setDate = function(year, month, day) {
    $scope.dt = new Date(year, month, day);
  };

  $scope.format = 'yyyy-MM-dd';
  $scope.altInputFormats = ['M!/d!/yyyy'];

  $scope.popup2 = {
    opened: false
  };

  var tomorrow = new Date();
  tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1);
  var afterTomorrow = new Date();
  afterTomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1);
  $scope.events = [
    {
      date: tomorrow,
      status: 'full'
    },
    {
      date: afterTomorrow,
      status: 'partially'
    }
  ];

  function getDayClass(data) {
    var date = data.date,
      mode = data.mode;
    if (mode === 'day') {
      var dayToCheck = new Date(date).setHours(0,0,0,0);

      for (var i = 0; i < $scope.events.length; i++) {
        var currentDay = new Date($scope.events[i].date).setHours(0,0,0,0);

        if (dayToCheck === currentDay) {
          return $scope.events[i].status;
        }
      }
    }

    return '';
  }
});
```

Here is the doc that I take the code: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: its working fine at my end, whats the exact issue?

Comment: It is working on Plunker too. I installed the npm modules and added required scripts but it is not working. I noticed that popovers at triggers also not working, but they work on button click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use jade with angularjs.
if you want to add date picker popup , you can use the code below
for html

```
<input type="text" uib-datepicker-popup="" name="dob" placeholder="Please enter date in YYYY-mm-dd format" 
  ng-model="dob" is-open="popup2.opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions"
  ng-required="true" close-text="Close" class="form-control"/>
<span class="input-group-btn">
  <button type="button" ng-click="open2()" class="btn btn-default">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
  </button>
</span>
```

and add this in your controller

```
$scope.dateOptions = {
  formatYear: 'yy',
  maxDate: new Date(2020, 5, 22),
  minDate: new Date(1970, 1, 1),
  startingDay: 1
};
$scope.open = function() {
  $scope.popup.opened = true;
};
$scope.popup = {
  opened: false
};
function getDayClass(data) {
  var date = data.date,
  mode = data.mode;
  if (mode === 'day') {
    var dayToCheck = new Date(date).setHours(0,0,0,0);
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.events.length; i++) {
      var currentDay = new Date($scope.events[i].date).setHours(0,0,0,0);
      if (dayToCheck === currentDay) {
        return $scope.events[i].status;
      }
    }
  }
  return '';
}
```

and this in your css file

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: It worked, thank you very much. But can you explain the problem more clearly?

Comment: @patel what is the use of having formatYear: 'yy', in dateoptions?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was not using npm (or bower) in my project. Hence I had to manually place the following files (downloaded from [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/master/template) ) in the path to make the calendar popup with dates when we use uib-datepicker-popup.

```
WebPages
L___uib
    L___template
       L____datepicker
           L____datepicker.html
           L____day.html
           L____month.html
           L____year.html
       L____datepickerPopup
           L____poup.html
```